# How are treated nonpersistent data in DevExpress XAF?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I need to create some queries and these queries will be used to create graphs in a dashboard. The queries are a lot of calculations and are nonpersistent classes.

First I created the class and only about this I have HPerformance_ListView and HPerformance_DetailView but I don't have a data provider to populate it. The system tries to populate it from EF context, that is not possible.

```
[NavigationItem]
[NonPersistent]
public class HPerformance
{
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public decimal Meta { get; set; }
    public decimal Percentual { get; set; }
}
```

And the query class

```
public class MetasVendas
{
    public MetasVendas()
    {
        fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
        toDate = DateTime.Now;
        revenda = 0;
    }

    public DateTime fromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime toDate { get; set; }
    public long revenda { get; set; }

    public BindingList<HPerformance> _hPerformance()
    {
        var r = _calculoMetaEValor();

        var rr = r.GroupBy(g => true).Select(s => new HPerformance()
        {
            Valor = s.Sum(v => v.TotalUSacess + v.TotalUSradio),
            Meta = s.Sum(v => v.Meta),
            Percentual = s.Sum(vv => vv.TotalUSacess + vv.TotalUSradio) / s.Sum(vv => vv.Meta)
        });

        return new BindingList<HPerformance>(rr.ToList());
    }
```

In the dashboard controller this is the code that I don't know how to handle. My example doesn't work

```
public partial class DashboardDealerGoalExecute : ViewController<DashboardView>
{
    void parametersViewItem_ControlCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DashboardViewItem viewItem = (DashboardViewItem)sender;

        if (viewItem.Id == "HPerformance")
        {
            ListView _hPerformance = (ListView)viewItem.InnerView;

            if (parameters != null && parameters.Dealer != null)
            {
                BindingList<HPerformance> hp =
                    new MetasVendas()
                    {
                        fromDate = parameters.FromDate,
                        toDate = parameters.ToDate,
                        revenda = parameters.Dealer.ID
                    }._hPerformance();
                _hPerformance.CurrentObject = hp;
            }
        }
```

`HPerformance` is a dashboard item and is connected to `HPerformance` class (1st code). How do I setup `HPerformance_ListView` to be populated by `_hPerformance()` method?

Thanks,
Marco Castro

Comment: Hi where you able to solve your problem?

Comment: You need to use DomainComponent for this purpose. Detailed info:  https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/116516/concepts/business-model-design/non-persistent-objects